# StretchBlt fails

Tags: .net, com, activex, stretchblt

I have a COM component. This COM components shows an image on the screen. The image bits are copied through a buffer like this:

```
IplImage iplimage = image;

IplImage *img2 = cvCreateImage(cvGetSize(&iplimage),
                           iplimage.depth,
                           iplimage.nChannels);

cvCopy(&iplimage, img2);

memcpy(m_BackSurface.vpBits, img2->imageData, img2->width*img2->height*3);
```

Where `image` is a cv::Mat. On certain conditions this is a cropped cv::Mat, ie. the return of the `raw_image(x0, y0, w, h)` where `raw_image` is another cv::Mat.

Later the application calls `StretchBlt` to show the image.

If I'm running this COM component inside a .NET application (and **only** when inside a .NET application this doesn't occurs on a pure unmanaged environment) the call to `StretchBlt` fails when (again, only when) `image` has been cropped. It does not fail on the code path where image isn't cropped. The drawing code is the same for both code paths. `GetLastError()` will return the error 8.

Can someone shed a light on this issue?

Answer (score 2):

Error code 8, [according to MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms681382%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), corresponds to `ERROR_NOT_ENOUGH_MEMORY`. Now that you're running in a .NET environment, you have less available memory since the CLR is loaded into your process. You should try to reduce memory usage, and look for memory leaks as well

Comment: Dario, thank you. Actually had I unsigned int that overflowed after being subtracted by a signed value greater than itself, feeding garbage data to StretchBlt. You said about leaks and I took a long look in the code and found it. Thank you!